# Flex event when drag is dropped outside a component

Tags: apache-flex, events, drag-and-drop

One of my components is handling drag and drop

```
<s:HGroup id="hgModules" 
      gap="0" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"
      dragOver="dragOver(event)" dragEnter="dragEnter(event)" dragDrop="dragDrop(event)" dragComplete="dragComplete(event)" dragExit="dragExit(event)">
```

My problem is, when something is dragged away from `hgModules` I am not getting any event whatsoever. Not even dragComplete.
For clarity, "outside" is a `Group` containing `hgModules` that does not process drops. Hence the dropping happens with the "invalid drop" white and red icon.

The question is : **What can I do to be notified** that the user released the left button outside `hgModules`?

Comment: You'll have to listen on the `stage` to get this to work. Have a look at the source code of `List` to see how it's done there (search for `systemManager.getSandboxRoot()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit shold go to RIAstar for pointing me in the right direction

```
            protected function onDragStart( event:MenuEvent):void {
                systemManager.getSandboxRoot().addEventListener(SandboxMouseEvent.MOUSE_UP_SOMEWHERE, onMouseDragUp, false, 0, true);
                systemManager.getSandboxRoot().addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseDragUp, false, 0, true);
            }


            protected function onMouseDragUp( event:Event):void {
                systemManager.getSandboxRoot().removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseDragUp, false);
                systemManager.getSandboxRoot().removeEventListener(SandboxMouseEvent.MOUSE_UP_SOMEWHERE, onMouseDragUp, false);
                dragDrop( event);
            }
```